# How to group random rows until they match a value?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm running a Oracle 11g query that returns results like these:

```
|ID|    VALUE|
|01|        2|
|02|        1|
|03|        5|
|04|        1|
|05|        4|
|06|        2|
```

So when I ask for "Group of IDs that it's sum is 4" I receive:

```
|01|        2|
|06|        2|
```

OR

```
|01|        2|
|02|        1|
|04|        1|
```

I don't care which group is it, it just have to be the exact SUM.

BONUS QUESTION: How to group random rows until they match CLOSE TO a value? + or -

EDIT: The query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT d.date, d.pdv, d.coo, SUM(i.itemTotal) total
                                             , SUM(CASE 
                                                    WHEN f.id > 0 THEN 0
                                                    ELSE 1
                                                   END) isInvalid
  FROM tb_doc d
  JOIN tb_docItem i ON i.pdv    = d.pdv
                   AND i.coo    = d.coo
                   AND i.status = 'V'
  JOIN map_product p ON p.id = i.productId
  LEFT JOIN tmp_family f ON f.id = p.productFamily
  WHERE d.date BETWEEN '01-DEZ-2013' AND '31-DEZ-2013'
  GROUP BY d.date, d.pdv, d.coo
) WHERE invalid = 0;
```

Comment: Show us your query, so we know way you are getting that result.

Comment: It's a complicated query, I don't think it really matters. But I'll post it in a few minutes.

Comment: So really you want a combination of rows returned by that query, showing `date, pdv, coo` where the sum of `total` is 4? Do you actually want 4 or is that just an example and the target might change? Roughly how many rows are you expecting from that query?

Comment: The actual total value of the group that I want is 10,119.58. There are 5600 rows and the value from each row can be anything from - 0.23 up to 748.95.

Comment: OK, quite different from the original statement then, at least in how it would need to be approached. Is there a limit to how many elements you'd accept in a group, or could you theoretically have all 5600 summing up to the total you want?

Answer (score 1):

The following query will return all groups of up to four elements where the sum is a given value:

```
select *
from table t1 left outer join
     table t2
     on t2.id > t1.id left outer join
     table t3
     on t3.id > t2.id left outer join
     table t4
     on t4.id > t3.id
where (coalesce(t1.value, 0) + coalesce(t2.value, 0) + coalesce(t3.value, 0) + 
       coalesce(t4.value, 0)
      ) = 4;
```

You can choose one of these rows by putting this in a subquery and doing `rownum = 1`.

To get closest to  certain value, the replace the `where` clause with:

```
order by abs(4 - (coalesce(t1.value, 0) + coalesce(t2.value, 0) +
                  coalesce(t3.value, 0) + coalesce(t4.value, 0)
                 )
            )
```

To handle an arbitrary number of values would require a recursive CTE, perhaps more trouble than is needed to solve your problem.

For your particular problem, just use `with` for your query:

```
with t as (<your query here>)
```

and following the instructions above.

Comment: That's what I was looking at pretty much, until I saw the underlying query and questioned whether the target was really exactly 4. And it's worse than I thought too since the values aren't even integers.

Comment: I was trying to make it simple to understand, but turns out it's not.

Comment: @GustavoFSx . . . The SQL method is probably easier than procedural code for this purpose.  But, SQL has to generate every possible combination and then work from there.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I dont understand what you said.